MAUI Carousel not changing items in real-time, blank slide, grey bar at the bottom on iOS
I am binding an ObservableCollection to a Carousel view and displaying images and text. What I am noticing is that if I change the contents of the ObservableCollection, the Carousel doesn't reflect the change in realtime. I have to swipe through a few items and only then does the item change. I cant figure out if this is a bug in my code or MAUI. This exact code worked just fine in Xamarin.
(1) When I press the button, I expect the Text to change (I have also tried this with the image and get the same faulty behavior). The text only changes after I swipe across and return to that same slide.
On iOS - the change can be seen after a few swipes. On Android, the change is never seen.

(2) some of the slides won't show the image or the text when you swipe through
On iOS - this issue is prevalent. On Android - not seeing this issue

(3) There is a grey bar that appears on swipe that randomly shows up at the bottom (directly above the indicator), how do I get rid of that?
On iOS - this issue is prevalent. On Android - not seeing this issue



There is a grey bar that appears on swipe that randomly shows up at
the bottom (directly above the indicator), how do I get rid of that?
On iOS - this issue -is prevalent. On Android - not seeing this issue

To get rid of the grey bar above the indicator on iOS, you can set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never", see Scroll bar visibility.
<CarouselView
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
            Grid.Row="1"
            IndicatorView="IndicatorView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>


some of the slides won't show the image or the text when you swipe
through On iOS - this issue is prevalent. On Android - not seeing this
issue

This issue is related with [BUG][iOS] Maui 8.0.10+ - CarouselView - Previous item content disappears after scrolling to next item #22015 and [iOS] Images from paths refuse to load in UI #19833. You can follow up there. Hopefully, it'll be fixed in next release.

On iOS - the change can be seen after a few swipes. On Android, the
change is never seen.

You need to make your Model: CarouselData implement ObservableObject using MVVM communitytoolkit. That'll update the UI automatically after changing the Text value: Data[0].Text = "CHANGED".
public partial class CarouselData : ObservableObject
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string? _text;
}


"You may need to update the ItemSource of CarouselView to change the property of the item in real-time:" -  this doesn't feel like the ideal use of ObservableCollection tho. The sample repro re-adding all works, but in a real app I want to simply modify a single record. Is this a bug? Moifying the collection directly worked in Xamarin just fine.

I think its something to do with INotifyPropertyChanged on the CarouselData model that is missing.

Found the answer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject

@Reza Nice catch! I've updated this in my answer, you can check it.:)

Your answer doesn’t quite work, you can’t set an observable property in a model and be able to access it everywhere. You need to write out the getter and setter as in the link I mentioned above.

Yes, both are the same and can be accessed. The ObservableProperty attribute would be a neater way, seeHow it works
